# jQuery changing links of each child inside an each loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the `CID` of each `.vehicleID` and append each `href` inside the `.vehicle-actions` class with `&VID=[CID]`

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="./garage_vehicle.php?mode=add_vehicle"><span>Create a Vehicle</span></a></li>

            <li class="vehicle-view toggleVehicleButton"><a class="vehicleID" href="./garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_own_vehicle&amp;CID=6"><span>2014 Audi A4</span></a>
                <div class="vehicle-actions" style="width: 179px; display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_vehicle">View Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=edit_vehicle">Edit Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a class="deletevehicle" href="">Delete Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_modification.php?mode=add_modification">Add Modification</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_premium.php?mode=add_premium">Add Insurance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_quartermile.php?mode=add_quartermile">Add Quartermile Time</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_dynorun.php?mode=add_dynorun">Add Dynorun</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_track.php?mode=add_lap">Add Lap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_service.php?mode=add_service">Add Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_own_vehicle">Set Main Vehicle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="vehicle-view toggleVehicleButton"><a class="vehicleID" href="./garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_own_vehicle&amp;CID=7"><span>2008 Chevrolet Corvette</span></a>
                <div class="vehicle-actions" style="width: 179px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_vehicle">View Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=edit_vehicle">Edit Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a class="deletevehicle" href="">Delete Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_modification.php?mode=add_modification">Add Modification</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_premium.php?mode=add_premium">Add Insurance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_quartermile.php?mode=add_quartermile">Add Quartermile Time</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_dynorun.php?mode=add_dynorun">Add Dynorun</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_track.php?mode=add_lap">Add Lap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_service.php?mode=add_service">Add Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_own_vehicle">Set Main Vehicle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

In my head it seems simple but I can't seem to grasp what I'm doing wrong

**jQuery**

```
function getURLParameter(url, name) {
    return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url)||[,null])[1];
}

$('.vehicleID').each(function(i, val){
    var vehicleIDurl = ($(this).attr('href'));
    var CID = getURLParameter(vehicleIDurl, 'CID');
    $('.vehicle-actions',this).each(function(i, val){
        editCID = $(this).find('a');
        editCID.attr('href', editCID.attr('href') + '&VID=' + CID);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look inside the `a.vehicleID` element but you should look inside its parent `li`.

Your code can be simplified. I would do this :

```
$('.vehicleID').each(function(i, val){
    var CID = getURLParameter(this.href, 'CID');
    $('.vehicle-actions a', $(this).closest('li')).attr('href', function(_, href){
         if (href.indexOf("&VID")!=-1) return href; 
         return href + '&VID=' + CID);
    });
});
```

Among the simplifications, I prefer `this.href` over `$(this).attr('href')` and I use [the version of the attr function taking a function as second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr).

Comment: What issue do you see ?

Answer (score 0):

This `piece` of code may not work,

```
$('.vehicle-actions',this).each(function(i, val){
    editCID = $(this).find('a');
    editCID.attr('href', editCID.attr('href') + '&VID=' + CID);
});
```

In `$('.vehicle-actions',this)` this will not identify the next `div.vehicle-actions` because it is not `a` child, so use its `closest li.vehicle-view` as a parent selector

Try this,

```
$('.vehicle-actions',$(this).closest('li.vehicle-view')).each(function(i, val){
    editCID = $(this).find('a');
    editCID.attr('href', editCID.attr('href') + '&VID=' + CID);
});
```

Comment: I've used this but this changes all the URL to `/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_vehicle&VID=7` when each of them has a different url

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified vehicleID in all  tag so below statement will returns only one element.

```
$('.vehicleID').length
```

So add class properly in all  tag.